# TCP Servers Dropping connections

Tags: windows-10, tcp

I am having an issue with my Windows machine(or network setup) dropping TCP server connections after about 4 transactions.

My Setup,
Windows 10 machine connected to router then out to the internet, with a forwarded port back to my machine.

Example,

- I start a TCP server with packet sender on port '10000'
- with my remote device( out side the network), I connect to the TCP server on my machine via the forwarded port and send some data
- the first few transactions will work expected.
- after 4 transactions the server will stop responding, the remote device can keep sending as it still thinks there is a server, but I do not see the data on the TCP server.

I can recreate this situation on my machine with any TCP server program(Hercules,Packet Sender etc...), including self written ones in C# and php.

Note: this only happens with devices outside of the network through the forwarded port, if it is local to the machine or network it works.

I have ruled out the sending devices as I can connect to other servers not on my network and it works as expected.

I suspect it is router\network setup, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Sounds like a crappy router which cant handle connection tracking properly. Either replace the router or replace tje firmware on it +does it work with dd-wrt?)

Comment: I do not have access to the router (I will need to contact IT :(), is there some feature that could be doing this so I can give them a place to start looking?

Comment: Its not likely something that can be fixed without replacing the firmware of the router.